# ¿Hay una forma de crear zerofill en SQL con números decimales ya que no encuentro ninguna información al respecto alguien sabe algo a respecto

Tags: mysql

```
drop table if exists libros;

create table libros(
  codigo int(6) zerofill auto_increment,
  titulo varchar(40) not null,
  autor varchar(30),
  editorial varchar(15),
  precio decimal(5,2) unsigned,
  cantidad smallint zerofill,
  primary key (codigo)
 );

insert into libros (titulo,autor,editorial,precio,cantidad)
  values('Martin Fierro','Jose Hernandez','Planeta',34.5,200);
insert into libros (titulo,autor,editorial,precio,cantidad)
  values('Aprenda PHP','Mario Molina','Emece',45.7,50);
insert into libros (titulo,autor,editorial,precio,cantidad)
  values('Cervantes y el quijote','Borges','Paidos',23,40);

select * from libros;

insert into libros (codigo,titulo,autor,editorial,precio,cantidad)
  values('545','El aleph', 'Borges', 'Emece',33,20);

select * from libros;

-- genera un error en versiones nuevas de MySQL 8.0 ya que no permite valores negativos con zerofill
insert into libros (codigo,titulo,autor,editorial,precio,cantidad)
  values(-400,'Matematica estas ahi', 'Paenza', 'Paidos',15.2,-100);

select * from libros;
```

Answer (score 0):

Veo dos cosas en tu código:

1. Con respecto a esta definición: `codigo int(6) zerofill auto_increment`: No tiene ningún sentido definir una columna del tipo incremental como `zerofill`. Realmente, para este caso, `zerofill` es algo que pertenece al contexto. Puede que en algún caso no necesites presentar la columna `codigo` con ceros a la izquierda. Y cuando la necesites, puedes usar funciones como `LPAD` in situ.
2. Con respecto a esta definición: `cantidad smallint zerofill` conviene que [leas atentamente lo que dice el MR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-attributes.html), porque muchas cosas están cambiando desde MySQL 8:

> As of MySQL 8.0.17, the `ZEROFILL` attribute is deprecated for numeric
> data types, as is the display width attribute for integer data types.
> You should expect support for `ZEROFILL` and display widths for
> integer data types to be removed in a future version of MySQL.
> Consider using an alternative means of producing the effect of these
> attributes. For example, applications can use the `LPAD()` function to
> zero-pad numbers up to the desired width, or they can store the
> formatted numbers in `CHAR` columns.
>
> ---
>
> A partir de MySQL 8.0.17, el atributo `ZEROFILL` está en desuso para
> los tipos de datos numéricos, al igual que el atributo de ancho de
> visualización para los tipos de datos enteros. Es de esperar que la
> compatibilidad con `ZEROFILL` y los anchos de visualización para los
> tipos de datos enteros se eliminen en una versión futura de MySQL.
> Considere el uso de un medio alternativo para producir el efecto de
> estos atributos. Por ejemplo, las aplicaciones pueden utilizar la
> función `LPAD()` para rellenar con ceros los números hasta el ancho
> deseado, o pueden almacenar los números formateados en columnas
> `CHAR`.

Haciendo esto (es opinión propia) MySQL empieza a corregir un error
que consistiría en querer meter en la definición de los datos algo que
es circunstancial: poder presentarlos en una forma u otra. Y esto es
positivo.

Entonces, si quieres presentar tu columna `cantidad`, puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
CASE  WHEN cantidad < 0
    THEN CONCAT('-',LPAD(ABS(cantidad),5,0))       
    ELSE LPAD(cantidad,5,0) END AS cantidad
```

Y para `codigo` usas `LPAD`, algo así: `LPAD(codigo,6,0) AS codigo`.

Veamos un fiddle completo:

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
drop table if exists libros;

create table libros( codigo int(6)  auto_increment, titulo varchar(40) not null, autor varchar(30), editorial varchar(15), precio decimal(5,2) unsigned, cantidad smallint , primary key (codigo) );

insert into libros (titulo,autor,editorial,precio,cantidad) values('Martin Fierro','Jose Hernandez','Planeta',34.5,200); insert into libros (titulo,autor,editorial,precio,cantidad) values('Aprenda PHP','Mario Molina','Emece',45.7,50); insert into libros (titulo,autor,editorial,precio,cantidad) values('Cervantes y el quijote','Borges','Paidos',23,40);

select * from libros;

insert into libros (codigo,titulo,autor,editorial,precio,cantidad) values('545','El aleph', 'Borges', 'Emece',33,20);

select * from libros;

-- genera un error en versiones nuevas de MySQL 8.0 ya que no permite valores negativos con zerofill 
insert into libros (codigo,titulo,autor,editorial,precio,cantidad) values(400,'Matematica estas ahi', 'Paenza', 'Paidos',15.2,-10);

select * from libros;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
    LPAD(codigo,6,0) AS codigo,
    titulo,
    autor,
    editorial,
    precio,
    CASE  WHEN cantidad < 0
        THEN CONCAT('-',LPAD(ABS(cantidad),5,0)) 
        ELSE LPAD(cantidad,5,0) END 
    AS cantidad        
FROM libros;
```

| codigo | cantidad | titulo | autor | editorial | precio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000001 | 00200 | Martin Fierro | Jose Hernandez | Planeta | 34.50 |
| 000002 | 00050 | Aprenda PHP | Mario Molina | Emece | 45.70 |
| 000003 | 00040 | Cervantes y el quijote | Borges | Paidos | 23.00 |
| 000400 | -00010 | Matematica estas ahi | Paenza | Paidos | 15.20 |
| 000545 | 00020 | El aleph | Borges | Emece | 33.00 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)